# How to find which part of code requires optimization?

Tags: python-3.x

Given two integers m, n (1 <= m <= n) find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square. 42 is one such a number.

Code works correctly on sample inputs but it is rejected by automatic code checker and reports timeout error and asks to optimize the code...

```
while m < n :
    list_divisors = []
    temp_list = []
    total = 0 

    for number in range (m+1) :
      if m%(number+1) == 0 :
          list_divisors.append(number+1)

    for number in list_divisors :
        total+= number*number
```

Codewars does not show what test cases it is failing for. It just shows Execution Timed Out (12000 ms) error.  Below test cases passed during sample check.

```
Test.assert_equals(list_squared(1, 250), [[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100]])
Test.assert_equals(list_squared(42, 250), [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]])
Test.assert_equals(list_squared(250, 500), [[287, 84100]])
```

Comment: The *general* answer to the question asked in the title is to use a profiler, which will tell you what percentage of your program's runtime is spent on which lines. See f/e the 3rd-party sampling profiler [`py-spy`](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy), or the standard-library deterministic profilers documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: You got a couple of answers to your question. If you find the answers satisfactory, you can put closure to your question by marking one of them as accepted; or you can wait for more answers to trickle in.

Comment: 'Profiler' - New term I learned. Seems like a good topic for weekend reading! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this based on your code. No data gets stored in a list. Total is the sum of squared of whole divisors. Then, if square-root of that total is a whole number, return the list.

```
import math

def list_squared(number):

    total = 0
    for x in range(1, number+1):
        if number % x == 0:
            total += x*x

    bounds = math.sqrt(total)
    if math.ceil(bounds) == math.floor(bounds):
        return [number, total]
    else:
        return False


def all_numbers(start, end):
    numbers = []
    for x in range(start, end+1):
        data = list_squared(x)
        if data != False:
            numbers.append(data)

    return numbers

x = all_numbers(1, 10000)
print(x)
```

1..10000 checks takes 4.7s. I am sure it can be optimized further. Does this help you?

## Even faster

Switching these two lines:

```
    total = 0
    for x in range(1, number+1):
```

with

```
    total = 1 + number*number
    for x in range(2, math.ceil((number+1)/2)):
```

will cut down your runtime to around half.

## Even faster..er

```
def list_squared(number):
    total = 0
    x = 1
    while x <= math.sqrt(number):
        if number % x == 0:
            if (number/x == x) :
                total += x*x
            else :
                total += x*x + (number/x)*(number/x)
        x += 1

    bounds = math.sqrt(total)
    if math.ceil(bounds) == math.floor(bounds):
        return [number, total]
    else:
        return False
```

If you were to change list_squared a bit to loop through only square root of the number, you will get a runtime of half a second. The idea behind it is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-divisors-natural-number-set-1/.

Let's take 42 as the number. Square root is 6.48. Let's just use 6. Start with 1. 42 is divisible by 1. 42 is also divisible by the result the division, which is 42.

Go to 2. 42 is divisible by 2. The result is 21. So, 21 is also a whole divisor. Repeat that through 6 and you've covered all divisors for 42. That cuts your runtime to sqrt(n) instead of half.

Comment: "loop through only square root of the number" - Great tip! This works and it passes the checker.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never update the values of `m` or `n`. So if `m < n` is `True` on the first iteration of your loop, it will always be `True` and your while loop will be infinite. This would explain the timeout, probably because Codewars stops your code from executing if it hasn't finished after 12000ms.

To remedy this, you will have to update either `m` or `n` inside your `while` loop so that eventually the condition `m < n` evaluates to `False`, at which point your code will "drop through" the `while` loop.